# Is it possible to have Brave's VPN not affect the whole computer on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, vpn, brave

When I turn on the VPN in Brave it seems to affect the whole computer, including other browsers. Is it possible to make it only affect Brave? I don't want Chrome to go through the same VPN. Actually, I don't even want other Brave profiles to go through the same VPN either.

Is it possible to configure Brave's VPN to behave that way?

Comment: BTW, you *definitely* don't want to use an email app, e.g. Thunderbird, on VPN, because the email might see you as opening your mail from a foreign country, and lock your account under the assumption that it's being hacked.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I haven't thought about that one, but yes, I want higher control over my VPN.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I tend to keep VPN running even when I don't really need it, and email is one thing I haven't had issues with so far. Captchas can get obnoxious, websites and online games which normally wouldn't ask for 2FA start doing it every time... Email just works.

Comment: @PabloFernandez, Recently, I was forced to change passwords on two accounts when I inadvertently left email running, with VPN apparent location a few thousand km away. Your mileage (kmtrage??) may vary.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to configure Brave's VPN to behave that way?

No, unfortunately it's not possible.

#### Explanation + possible solution

When speaking about VPN, *generally* we are talking about a **system-wide** solution. All outgoing traffic goes through the **encrypted tunnel**. Not only the `HTTP` and `HTTPS` procotols. Once the tunnel is established, all network packets pass through this tunnel. There are exceptions for corporate VPNs which are used to access internal resources from outside (not to hide our IP or access content from another country).

Brave VPN is no exception to the rule and redirect all network traffic. This is why it affects your other browsers.

> Brave VPN blocks trackers and encrypts and protects every connection
> to the Web. That's every app, on any device, across desktop, Android,
> and iOS.

What you are looking for is similar to an `HTTP proxy`. **However**, HTTP proxies **do not encrypt data** and will affect other browsers too. This is not the solution.

**Conclusion :** I would advise you to use a solution like a Chrome extention called `Browsec` (**or another similar solution**). [Here](https://browsec.com/en/) is the link for `browsec`. These kind of solutions act like a `VPN` **only inside the web browser**. There are several, I'll let you make your choice.